# this is question about IBM app connect enterprise

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

how to store integration node name, server name, application name, request and response in a database whenever the message is being sent as a request.
can you please send the ESQL code.
as soon as possible
Thank you....

Answer (score -1):

You can do all of that with monitoring events and Business Transaction Monitor.

Comment: But how? Please also add a reference